# Type bounds unexpectedly change precedence of Scala implicit parameter resolution

Tags: scala, implicit

The Scala example below shows a situation where a required implicit parameter (of type `TC[C]`) can be provided by both implicit methods in scope, `a` and `b`. But when run, no ambiguity results, and it prints "B".

```
object Example extends App{
  trait A
  trait B extends A
  class C extends B

  class TC[X](val label: String)

  implicit def a[T <: A]: TC[T] = new TC[T]("A")
  implicit def b[T <: B]: TC[T] = new TC[T]("B")

  println(implicitly[TC[C]].label)
}
```

Note that the only different between implicit methods `a` and `b` are the type bounds, and both of them can match `TC[C]`. If the method `b` is removed, then `a` is implicitly resolved instead.

While I find this behaviour convenient in practice, I'd like to understand whether it is a specified language feature, or just an implementation quirk.

Is there a language rule or principle by which the compiler prioritizes `b` over `a`, rather than viewing them as equivalent and thus ambiguous options?

Answer (score 3):

There is a rule about this prioritization, which says that the most specific out of the two matches will get a higher priority. From [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), under 6.26.3 'Overloading Resolution':

> The relative weight of an alternative A over an alternative B is a number from 0 to 2, deﬁned as the sum of
>
> - 1 if A is as speciﬁc as B, 0 otherwise, and
> - 1 if A is deﬁned in a class or object which is derived from the class or object deﬁning B, 0 otherwise.
>
> A class or object C is derived from a class or object D if one of the
>   following holds:
>
> - C is a subclass of D, or
> - C is a companion object of a class derived from D, or
> - D is a companion object of a class from which C is derived.

Comment: Does the SLS say anything directly about bounds on type parameters? In other words, what is the technical meaning of "A is as specific as B"?

Comment: I think it only talks about choosing alternatives in general, which in case of <: bounds is applied to the upper bound. I understand "A is as specific as B" as "A and B are the same number of levels from a common parent". Makes sense?